# change storage class a folder gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

change storage class in a folder into a bucket in GCP, I try with

```
gsutil rewrite -s coldline gs://bucket-name/folder/
```

I see the

```
gsutil stat gs://bucket-name/folder/
```

what am I doing wrong?

[image: shell]

[image: dashboard]

Answer (score 1):

The configuration tab on the console refers to the configuration of your main bucket, **not** the folder which you changed the storage class to `COLDLINE`. As seen on your screenshot, the folder `test-2` is already configured into `COLDLINE`. You should be able to confirm it on the console by going to the folder and look at the "Storage Class" column.

Comment: Pherhaps cant assigned storageclass directly to a folder into a bucket, the stat of object (folder) i am not clear, the gsutil stat show that a object (folder) have stotarage class different from what is shown on the dashboard

Comment: The configuration tab (on the dashboard) is displaying the default storage class of your bucket. However, you can also change the storage class of the objects inside the bucket by running the `gsutil rewrite` which you've ran successfully but it doesn't mean that the storage class of your bucket would change. Only the storage class of the objects inside the folder you've specified will change and that explains why on the configuration tab of the bucket you can see it as Standard contrary to what you can see on the objects inside the folder which is already Coldline.